# AzureDevops to Jira integration

Tags: azure-devops, jira, jira-plugin

In our project, we are using Azure git for the repo and we are doing the commit in Visual studio 2019.
I have a requirement to show the  Jira numbers in the "related work item section" while committing the code. Please help

Visual Studio Related Work Item

[image: img_work_item]

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Did it help you with your question?

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid the Jira numbers cannot be shown in the `related work item section` of VS2019. This feature is intergrated with azured devop. The field `related work item section` can only show the work items in your azure devops project.

If you want to link the code commit to a jira issue. You can use the the [Git Integration for Jira Cloud](https://bigbrassband.wistia.com/medias/cs229y2gzj) app, or [Azure Git Listener for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221787/azure-git-listener-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) app to connect your azure repo to your Jira cloud. Then you just need to include jira issue numbers in your commit comment. You can check [this thread](https://bigbrassband.com/git-integration-for-jira/documentation/linking-git-commits-to-jira-issues.html) for more information.

If you want manage jira issues from VS 2019 you can check out [Atlassian Connector for Visual Studio](https://atlassian-docs.bitbucket.io/IDEPLUGIN-VS/Installing-the-Visual-Studio-Connector_211058799.html).

You can also check out the official extension [Jira and Bitbucket](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atlassian.atlascode) for VSCode.

You can also try syncing your Jira issue with azure devops. Please check out the detailed steps [here](https://www.idalko.com/jira-azure-devops-integration/). Then you will be able to view the work items in the `related work item section` field of VS2019, but these work items are synced to azure devops from Jira, they are not the originAL Jira issue from Jira cloud